# How to subscribe to UX Events

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I'm currently using the UxExceptionListener.cs class to subscribe to Tango Exceptions in order to make sure I'm in a valid state when I record a frame.

```
void Start () 
{
    UxExceptionListener UX = UxExceptionListener.GetInstance;
    UX.RegisterOnCamerUnderExposed(OnCameraUnderExposed);
}

void OnCameraUnderExposed (string exposure) 
{
    Debug.Log("My camera is underexposed " + exposure);
}
```

However that disables depth. Does anyone know the proper way of doing it ?

Comment: is that related to unity3d?

Comment: Yes that's is running in Unity

Comment: Would you please share the event handler code as well? It's hard to say what might be happening based on these two lines alone.  

Also, please perform an "adb logcat" while running your application and share that. It will make debugging the issue much easier.

Comment: Closing the loop... after I upgraded the SDK to the latest version, the problem was gone. Thanks for the input.